# Google Sheets: Avoid #DIV/0! In ArrayFormula()

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, divide-by-zero

I'm looking for the way to avoid the #DIV/0! error in an ArrayFormula. Originally the cell formula was:

```
=arrayformula(F2:F3406/G2:G3406)
```

I've since tried:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(F2:F3406/G2:G3406,''))
=iferror(arrayformula(F2:F3406/G2:G3406),'')
```

However, these both give #ERROR!, with the comment 'Formula parse error'.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/(F2:F3406/G2:G3406))))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/(F2:F3406/G2:G3406)), 0))
```

Comment: Thanks, used the first formula, that works. But, I don't understand how it works... would you mind explaining it's logic pls?

Comment: you cant divide by zero so if F/G is 0 then 1/0 will result in DIV error and then IFERROR will remove these errors. but if F/G isnt zero it gets divided some small number but dividing it again by 1 will bring back initial values

Comment: Clever! And I sort of understand it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be :
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(IFERROR(Range1/Range2)))

That is in this example
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(IFERROR(F2:F3406/G2:G3406)))